# How to retrieve a database entry and assign it to a variable in asp.net MVC5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I'm totally new in MVC5 code first and I'm totally lost at the moment. I find it hard to retrieve a value in the database so I can use them for comparison, range and database update reasons.

This is the scenario:

```
    //Second Model
    public int TransactionID { get; set; }

    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public virtual Product ProductName { get; set; }

    public int Quantity { get; set; }
```

First Model

```
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    public string ProductName { get; set;}

    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public virtual Category ProductCategory { get; set; }

    [Range(0,99)]
    public int ItemIn { get; set; }

    [Range(0, 99)]
    public int ItemOut { get; set; }
```

So what I wanted to do is subtract 'Quantity' from 'ItemIn' and add it to 'ItemOut' the moment the user create or edit a transaction.
I hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check into using your entity framework correctly. EF (Entity Framework) will automatically map data to your model. Then you can use LINQ or other functions to retrieve specific rows/row and you will have the information. Calling .SaveChanges() inside the using context will update the any information you have changed in the using context.

```
using (var db = new SomeEntity()) {\
 var productId = 3;
 var item = db.FirstModels.Find(productId);
 if (item != null) {
   item.In = 4;
   item.Out = 5;
 }
 db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response.